# Add panels inside a panel dynamically on button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add panel to already existing panel with name Tablica
but im doing it wrong im increasing the global variable each time i add the a panel so the new added panel has different Y location and this makes my panels not overlapping eachother.
But now i want to use a different approach so that i dont add them with fixed X,Y location and instead i somehow dock them on top and each new panel addded stays at the top of the parent panel so in other words the last panel added when the button is clicked stays on top of the Tablica panel

This is the code i use now which works except that the last panel is added at the bottom of the panel:

```
int TabliciLocation = 30; //global variable
private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel newPanel = new Panel();
    newPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 52);
    newPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, TabliciLocation);
    Tablica.Controls.Add(newPanel);
    TabliciLocation += 60;
}
```

So the new approach has to be something like this :

```
 private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel newPanel = new Panel();
        newPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 52); 
        newPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Top; // if this can help    
        Tablica.Controls.Add(newPanel);

    }
```

Comment: Docking more than one control at any side is not recommended as docking ties to fill the side, - so what would you expect? Simply set the sizes and locations as needed! How many panels do you want to add? You could set the new top to the last bottom..

Comment: If you want to shift down the previous panels you either need to move them all or go for a flowlayoutpanel!

Comment: I tested your new approach and it seems to work ok. Last panel added goes to the top.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `FlowLayoutPanel` was made for this.

Here is an example; I use different `BackColors` to show how each new `Panel` pushes the previous ones down:

[image][image][image]

```
Random R = new Random();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.Name = "panel" + (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count + 1);
    p.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(123, R.Next(222), R.Next(222));
    p.Size = new Size(flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize.Width, 50);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(p, 0);  // this moves the new one to the top!
    // this is just for fun:
    p.Paint += (ss, ee) => {ee.Graphics.DrawString(p.Name, Font, Brushes.White, 22, 11);};
    flowLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
}
```