# C# text box similar to Sticky Notes in Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

I would like to add rectangular regions with text like StickyNotes application in Windows. In Windows sticky notes you can add rectangular regions, and by clicking them you can change the text inside of them. Also in sticky Notes you can add these rectangular with the button click.

I would like to have a similar effect, but I don't know Which component should I use from the Visual Studio 2019 Toolbar Menu?

[image]

Sticky Notes after the click:

[image]

**I am using Winform, Visual Studio 2019 and coding with C#.**

Comment: You can add a command to the textbox to spawn a new form that resembles the sticky note. This won't be in the VS tool menu, though. You will want to make a new class for the note 'after the click' and then add the logic to create it inside the code behind for the textbox. You should also edit your question to specify what GUI tools you are using. WPF? WinForms? MFC? UWP?

Comment: Textboxes looks different than the sticky notes rectangles. In sticky notes you can only edit the text by clicking them. After you click a window pops-out and you can edit afterwards as in the second image in my question. Should I use Panels instead? @dmedine

Comment: Make the textbox read only if you don't want it editable. But this doesn't seem to be what your question is about. It seems to be about spawning the form that resembles the sticky note dialog. Also, adjusting the look and feel (and a lot else) depends on what framework you are using. You should edit your post to say what framework you are using. Otherwise no one will be able to form a helpful answer to your question.

Comment: @dmedine I edited, below my question with bold text. It is Winform VS 2019 C# Application. What else you want to know?

Comment: @dmedine and Again the textbox size is fixed, you cannot change the height of the textbox, If I am not wrong.

Comment: @dmedine please check this link out [flowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581539/add-panels-inside-a-panel-dynamically-on-button-click) This is pretty much similar logic, however it needs a scrol and click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little research I reliazed that I could be able to achive same effect with the Panel and FlowLayout. I created a main `TodoListFlowLayout` inside my Form and I created another button to control this `TodoListFlowLayout`. With the button click I populated the FlowLayout as below:

```
Random random = new Random(); // Make it critiacally depended.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel toDoElement = new Panel();

    toDoElement.Name = "panel" + (TodoListFlowLayout.Controls.Count + 1);
    toDoElement.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(123, random.Next(222), random.Next(222));
    toDoElement.Size = new Size(TodoListFlowLayout.ClientSize.Width, 50);

    TodoListFlowLayout.Controls.Add(toDoElement);
    TodoListFlowLayout.Controls.SetChildIndex(toDoElement, 0);  
                                                     
    toDoElement.Paint += (ss, ee) => { ee.Graphics.DrawString(toDoElement.Name, Font, Brushes.White, 22, 11); };
    TodoListFlowLayout.Invalidate();
}
```

You can create click event by:

```
toDoElement.Click += todo_Element_Panel_Click;
```

and the function by:

```
void todo_Element_Panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

And lastly you can make it scrollable by

```
    TodoListFlowLayout.AutoScroll = false;
    TodoListFlowLayout.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
    TodoListFlowLayout.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
    TodoListFlowLayout.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
    TodoListFlowLayout.AutoScroll = true;
```

Output can be seen as below:

[image]